# Installing Application Insights as an Azure App Service Extension or via NuGet?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-web-app-service

It's possible to install Application Insights via the extensions section in Azure App Services, but it's also possible to just install the packages via NuGet and define the `APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY` application setting. You can also do both.

What is the difference?

Edit:

I have found what the differences are between installing the extension or the NuGet packages:

> You can configure monitoring by instrumenting the app in either of two ways:
>
> Run-time - You can select a performance monitoring extension when your web app is already live. It isn't necessary to rebuild or re-install your app. You get a standard set of packages that monitor response times, success rates, exceptions, dependencies, and so on.
>
> Build time - You can install a package in your app in development. This option is more versatile. In addition to the same standard packages, you can write code to customize the telemetry or to send your own telemetry. You can log specific activities or record events according to the semantics of your app domain.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-azure-web-apps#run-time-or-build-time

But what if you do both? Will there be anything beneficial about it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But what if you do both? Will there be anything beneficial about it?

- The extension detects that your app has already brought Application Insights with it and won't do anything, except dropping a profiler, which helps collect full SQL Statement in Dependencies. Without the profiler full SQL Statement won't be collected but everything else should just work fine.
  (If you are using 2.3.0 or earlier of SDK or if you application is targeting old .NET Framework like 4.0, then profiler does better correlation of dependencies as well.

In short, Starting with 2.4.0 of SDK, the only advantage of installing extension on top on nuget installation is to get full SQL Statements in Dependency Telemetry.

Answer (score 1):

> But what if you do both? Will there be anything beneficial about it?

As you know we could  install the packages via NuGet to use Application Insights .For this way, we could add custom telemetry data in my code,and monitor the telemetry data in application insights tools in Visual Studio. This will be very convenient. You could also refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-custom-events-metrics) to add custom telemetry data.

Code in MVC Porject:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("my trace info Home/Index");
            var telemetry = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();
            RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry();
            telemetry.TrackTrace("Home/Index Main");
            telemetry.TrackPageView("Home/Index");
            return View();
        }
```

The telemetry data in Application insight tool:

[image]

The application insights in **App Service**,you can only see limited data and trends in past 24 hours. This is very convenient for you to view the main telemetry data  in the app service directly. But if you want to know more details, that is not a good choose.

[image]

The most comprehensive monitor data and services are in **application insight service**. You could click '**View more in application insights**' in App Service monitor extension to go. Or you could go to application insight service directly.

[image]

**Time Range** in application insight service(include custom time range).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Are you certain that installing the extension only results in 24h only results? I could not find anything about it.

Comment: Open web app>Monitoring>Application Insights>see Slowest Requests (past 24 hours). And you can not find where to change the time range(screenshot 2). There only are Slowest Requests and Live Stream. The functions are very limit. So I don't suggest this way to see data.

Comment: But you could click request name in Slowest Requests  to see more details in application insights service.

Comment: The last screenshot has a "Time range" button, are you certain it does not go past 24hrs?

Comment: The last screenshot is in app insight service. It has the comprehensive functions. You could select many time ranges.  In my comment, I say the screenshot2(app insight extension in web app) only has 24 hours. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I do, but wouldn't you have the comprehensive functions available to you anyhow when using the extension only? I am aware that adding the SDK adds more fine grained details in potential, though I am doubting that installing the extension only is only has 24 hrs of data available.

Comment: If your link, Explore the data> step 2, it redirects the  app insight in monitoring in app service to app insight service.So you could operate more functions.The app insight service and SDK in local machine are ok. I just say the app insight in monitoring in app service has limit functions for you to operate.

Comment: The app insight in monitoring in app service like a simple version about app insight(only has slowest request and Live Stream function).  Hope you know.